# React navigation override backbutton behavior but don't change view

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to override action behavior in headerLeft (back button), but I don't want to change view, use default view of react navigation.

How to override, and add action to default headerLeft backButton?

Thanks

Comment: give a +1 to this PR https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/pull/2712 , right now, you'd have to pass own `headerLeft` component and render BackButton from there.

Answer (score -1):

to disappear default back button:

```
static navigationOptions =({navigation}) => {
    return {

        headerLeft: null,
    }  
}
```

you can also override your back button the same way